# Python OpenCV - Trying to identify a completely visible tile (all four edges are visible) and draw a green contour edges

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am working on a project to click images of the tiles and using OpenCV to to find out that the tile is visit-able or not.

Accessible tile should be shown as below -

[image: a green contour is shown on visit-able tile]

In the image below tile is not visit-able.

[image]

Code i have written is identifying multiple contours.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image1  = cv2.imread('floor3.jpg')#, cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR | cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)
orig = image1.copy()
cv2.imshow("Game Boy Screen", orig)
cv2.waitKey(0)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 11, 17, 17)
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 200)
flag, thresh = cv2.threshold(edged, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

try: hierarchy = hierarchy[0]
except: hierarchy = []

height, width, _ = image1.shape
min_x, min_y = width, height
max_x = max_y = 0

# computes the bounding box for the contour, and draws it on the frame,
for contour, hier in zip(contours, hierarchy):
    (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    min_x, max_x = min(x, min_x), max(x+w, max_x)
    min_y, max_y = min(y, min_y), max(y+h, max_y)
    if w > 80 and h > 80:
        cv2.rectangle(orig, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)

if max_x - min_x > 0 and max_y - min_y > 0:
    cv2.rectangle(orig, (min_x, min_y), (max_x, max_y), (255, 0, 0), 3)

cv2.imshow("Game Boy Screen", orig)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Below is the output i am getting -

[image: Instead of 1 contour as shown in first image i am getting multiple contours]

Original image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Original**:

- First, you should also put your original image.
- Second, using `minAreaRect` other than `boundingRect` to find the rotated rectangles.

---

**Update**:

I don't think do `findContours` on Canny edges is a good idea. I just do it on `threshed binary image`, then remove the contours with small area. So we can get the boundary of regions.**Then how to judge whether the region is complete or not, it's upto your math knowledge**.

[image]

---

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2017.12.09 00:25:47 CST
# 2017.12.09 14:26:01 CST
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("test.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 11, 17, 17)
th, threshed = cv2.threshold(gray, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cnts = cv2.findContours(threshed,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]

canvas = np.zeros_like(img, np.uint8)
H,W = img.shape[:2]
AREA = H*W
for cnt in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if(area<AREA/100):
        continue
    _ = cv2.drawContours(canvas, [cnt], -1, (0,255,0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)


cv2.imwrite("result.png", canvas)
```

---

Update 2:
After get the contours of regions, then how to judge whether it's complete or not?

**You should define what is complete?** In this situation, **the complete tile means it is a quadrilateral, four corner points, almost equal lengths of side**. Then you program the condition to tell the computer how to judge. *It's your job, you should try to solve it by yourself first.*
[image]

Total code and the result:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2017.12.09 00:25:47 CST
# 2017.12.09 14:26:01 CST
# 2017.12.09 17:52:17 CST
import cv2
import numpy as np

## lambda: calc distance
dist = lambda pt1, pt2: ((pt1[0]-pt2[0])**2 + (pt1[1]-pt2[1])**2)**0.5

img = cv2.imread("img04.jpg")

## (1) filter, threshed
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 11, 17, 17)
th, threshed = cv2.threshold(gray, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

## (2) findContours
cnts = cv2.findContours(threshed,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]


## (3) some variables
H,W = img.shape[:2]
AREA = H*W
xcnts = []
R = 0.8

## (4) judge wether the contour is belongs to a complete tile
for cnt in cnts:
    ## （4.1） filter by area
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if(area<AREA/100):
        continue
    ## （4.2） calc arpprox contour
    arclen = cv2.arcLength(cnt, closed=True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, arclen*0.02, closed=True)
    ## （4.3） filter by "complete ruler"
    ## "the complete tile means it is a quadrilateral, four corner points, almost equal lengths of side"
    pts = np.array(approx).reshape(-1,2)
    if len(pts) == 4:
        lens = np.array(list(dist(pts[i], pts[(i+1)%4]) for i in range(4)))
        flag = True
        for x in lens:
            if not (R< x/lens[0] < 1.0/R):
                flag = False
                continue
        if flag:
            xcnts.append(cnt)

## (5) draw and save
res = img.copy()
for cnt in xcnts:
    cv2.drawContours(res, [cnt], -1, (0,255,0), -1, cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.imwrite("00result.png", res)
```

[image]

---

**Update 3 (The last update)**:

I use the fixed threshed value in the my code just because your image contains a large dark origin. As for this image

[image],

there is no large dark, so change the threshold flag to `cv2.THRESH_OTSU`， and modify the area thresh to `AREA/20` or larger, modify the R smaller such as `R=0.7`.

Then I get the result:

[image]

---

Similar questions:

(1) [How to find the object on the noisy background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48181764/image-processing-using-opencv-and-python/48188499#48188499)

(2) [Python OpenCV - Trying to identify a completely visible tile (all four edges are visible) and draw a green contour edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47709162/python-opencv-trying-to-identify-a-completely-visible-tile-all-four-edges-are/47710320#47710320)

Comment: thanks for your response. I have added the original image.

Comment: on using boundingRect  as suggested, i am getting following error -     (x,y,w,h) = cv2.minAreaRect(contour)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)

Comment: @Ankit I test using your original image, and find it's not easy to detect it. And I found some question in your code. After `Canny edges` detection, we can find the edges, but the edges are not continuous and closed. So when do `findContours`, we find the contours of discontinuous and open edges, not of the regions. (Usually, I do findContours on threshed binary image). And in your image, the rectangle was transformed to diamond, so the `cv2.minAreaRect` (used for detecting rotated rectangle, `(x1,y2), (x2,y2), angle = cv2.minAreaRect(pts)`) also becomes invalid.

Comment: @Ankit try to `findContours` on the threshold binary image, not on the canny edges.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Silencer. It resolved a major part of the issue. However there is still a part of issue pending. What I need is that green contour should be drawn on the tile which is completely visible. In this particular case, its the central tile. As i mentioned in the question, tiles which are partially visible or are fully / partially occupied with the racks / objects should not be shown with green contour. I would be really grateful if you could help me in solving this last leg of the the issue.

Comment: @Ankit as I said in my answer, `Then how to judge whether the region is complete or not, it's upto your math knowledge.` First `you should define what is complete`? In your situation, `the complete tile means it is a quadrilateral, four corner points, almost equal lengths of side`. Then you `program the condition to tell the computer how to judge`. `It's your job, you should try to solve it by yourself`.

Comment: Thanks @Silencer. This is absolutely perfect. Marked it as answer.  I happen to test it on another image. Result is little disappointing but anyways ... i am a little new to image-processing. Just in case you wish to help me generalize this code or guide me in that direction, would be a great help.  link - https://imgur.com/a/XG893

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your patience in responding my followup queries. I changed the threshhold parameter line to "th, threshed = cv2.threshold(gray, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)" and changed the Area line to "if(area<AREA/20):". But somehow result is not appearing as your screenshot. Can you please post your complete code (one that includes the multi-colored contours on canvas) for the second image. I know you mentioned "Last Update" believe me it is last query...:)

Comment: I use the code of my other (secret) project. Extract the core code and post in the answer. I won't  post details, but your can do by yourself. And the tag (6) is the last result, you can reproduce tag(6). More job should be done by yourself. `This is the last replay, goodnight (2017.12.10 01:18 in China)`

Comment: No problem mate.I completely understand. Can you please verify the changes you made for the second image since i am not able to replicate it with the two changes you mentioned in you comment. first change is -> "th, threshed = cv2.threshold(gray, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)"  and second change is "if(area<AREA/20):". These changes I have done in the "complete code" you shared in your answer. I have tried all the possible combinations of thresholds and area.

Comment: @A_N Then try to modified the  R smaller like that `R = 0.7`