# How to find the object on the noisy background?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have been working on a project in which i have to find the x and y co-ordinates of the object using a global shutter camera in trigger mode.
Till now everything is working fine and i am getting the desired result but the problem is when i'm continuously processing the images in trigger mode i'm getting few extra readings of the image with noise.

The source image:

[image]

Can anyone suggest me with a good approach to solve this.

```
from scipy.spatial import distance as dist
from imutils import perspective
from imutils import contours
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2

def midpoint(ptA, ptB):
    return ((ptA[0] + ptB[0]) * 0.5, (ptA[1] + ptB[1]) * 0.5)


image = cv2.imread('022.bmp')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(7,7),0)

edged = cv2.Canny(gray,50,100)
edged = cv2.dilate(edged,None, iterations=1)
edged = cv2.erode(edged, None, iterations=1)

cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]

(cnts, _) = contours.sort_contours(cnts)
colors = ((0,0,255),(240,0,159),(0,165,255),(255,255,0),(255,0,255))
refObj = None

for c in cnts:
    if cv2.contourArea(c)<250:
        #print "in if loop"
        continue
    #print cv2.contourArea(c)
    box = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
    box = cv2.cv.BoxPoints(box) if imutils.is_cv2() else cv2.boxPoints(box)
    box = np.array(box,dtype="int")

    box = perspective.order_points(box)

    cX = np.average(box[:,0])
    cY = np.average(box[:,1])

    if refObj is None:
        (tl,tr,br,bl) = box
        (tlblX, tlblY) = midpoint(tl,bl)
        (trbrX, trbrY) = midpoint(tr,br)

        D = dist.euclidean((tlblX,tlblY),(trbrX,trbrY))
        refObj = (box, (cX,cY),D)
        print refObj[0]
        print 'cx-1',cX
        print 'cy-1',cY
        continue

orig = image.copy()
cv2.drawContours(orig,[box.astype("int")], -1, (0,255,0), 2)
cv2.drawContours(orig, [refObj[0].astype("int")],-1,(0,255,0),2)

refCoords = np.vstack([refObj[0],refObj[1]])
objCoords = np.vstack([box, (cX,cY)])

print box
print 'cx',cX
print 'cy',cY

for ((xA,yA), (xB,yB), color) in zip(refCoords,objCoords,colors):
    cv2.circle(orig, (int(xA),int(yA)),5,color,-1)
    cv2.circle(orig, (int(xB),int(yB)),5,color,-1)
    cv2.line(orig, (int(xA),int(yA)),(int(xB),int(yB)),color,2)




cv2.imshow('img',orig)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Can you suggest something on this?
Thank you!

Update, the solution provided by @silencer is working good but with this image i can't recognize the object.[image]

Comment: maybe if you filter by color (inRange function) you may get better result, or maybe a filter to reduce the noise perhaps, like median filter or different parameters in the gaussian filter perhaps

Comment: @api55 I'm trying to set a ROI such that i will only process this two object's and rest of the image get's excluded.What do you say.

Comment: A ROI will probably work good. Also if both images are roughly in the same place every time you can make the ROI the same for every image. However try filtering by color (yellow and brown) and you may get better results.

Comment: You `findContours` on the edge, while it is not a good practice on noisy image. Better to do it on `thresholded` image.

Answer (score 3):

I backup your source image, avoid you replace or delete it.

[image]

I analysis the image in different ColorSpace, and find the `B(BGR)` channel is good for your task.

[image]

---

Then do following steps:

1. Read and extract the blue channel.
2. Threshold the blue channel.
3. Find contours.
4. Filter by area.

[image]

---

The code and the result.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2017.12.09 00:25:47 CST
# 2018.01.10 21:10:07 CST
import cv2
import numpy as np


## (1) read and extract the blue channel
img = cv2.imread("img01.png")
blue = img[...,0]

## (2) threshold the blue
th, threshed = cv2.threshold(blue, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

## (3) find contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(threshed,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]

## (4) filter by AREA
canvas = img.copy()
H,W = img.shape[:2]
AREA = H*W

for cnt in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if not AREA/100<area<AREA/20:
        continue
    box = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(box)
    box = np.array(box,dtype="int")
    cv2.drawContours(canvas, [box], -1,(255,0,255) , 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

## save
cv2.imwrite("result.png", canvas)
```

[image]

---

Similar questions:

(1) [How to find the object on the noisy background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48181764/image-processing-using-opencv-and-python/48188499#48188499)

(2) [Python OpenCV - Trying to identify a completely visible tile (all four edges are visible) and draw a green contour edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47709162/python-opencv-trying-to-identify-a-completely-visible-tile-all-four-edges-are/47710320#47710320)

Comment: Thanks It worked,but i am getting noisy result in other images.

Comment: My code is special for this image(such as the thresh value, the blue channel). But the idea is common. More steps need to be done for others.

Comment: I have Uploaded a new image that's why i deleted the other can you suggest something on this, i have tried other methods but i couldn't find the few objects.

Comment: @vallabh It's impolite to modify the source image! It is totally different with the original. As I said, the idea is common. Have you really learn from it? And you steal my code to your question! So the question became total different.

Comment: I'm new here as i didn't know it so i changed the image.i have replaced the original image,Thank you

Comment: And thanks for correcting me i have replaced the original image.

Comment: @vallabh You can add similar or different images. But keep the original one if someone has answer using the original. It's better to add necessary typical example images when you ask the question. If you want to supply, keep the original(images/code/statements), and add new things. If the change make question's meaning become different, you should start another question.

Comment: Yes,I understood the procedure now.i have a doubt actually,you used Thresh value.i am trying it by using image filtering(Gaussian blur) algo then use canny edge detection.
can we also achieve the desired goal by using this?

Comment: Generally, no.  Because canny-edge-detecting on the blurred noisy image generate `edges(mostly opened)`, not `contours(closed edges)`. Then if you find contours on the edges, you mostly can't find the objects.

Comment: I have updated a new image,I have tired it using your given solution. i didn't get the result i also used other algo and changed the light intensity/extracted the other planes (Red and green).but i didn't the result.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend better initial preprocessing, removing noise before applying edge detection. One possible way would be applying bilateral filtering, which smoothes images, but at the same time preserves edges.

Here a quick example:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('img01.png')
canvas = img.copy()

filtered = cv2.bilateralFilter(img, 30, 80, 80)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(filtered, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
edged = cv2.Canny(gray,50,100)

_, cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(edged,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

H,W = img.shape[:2]
AREA = H*W

for cnt in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if not AREA/100<area<AREA/20:
        continue
    box = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(box)
    box = np.array(box,dtype="int")
    cv2.drawContours(canvas, [box], -1,(255,0,255) , 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

result = np.hstack((img, filtered, cv2.cvtColor(edged, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR), canvas))
cv2.imwrite("result.png", result)
cv2.imshow('Results', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

Moreover, you can take more drastic measures, by applying mean-shift filtering, which reduces the number of Colors in the image. Just replace the bilateral filter with:

```
filtered = cv2.pyrMeanShiftFiltering(img, 20, 50)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you,I will try this also.

Comment: You should checkout the documentation, as the parameters are image size dependent. Moreover, you can tune the color distance.
see https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#bilateralfilter

Comment: Added an alternative more drastic filter approach.

Comment: Yes,i have managed to find it.Both the algo's work perfectly.Thank you!